Bruno Mars pitched down a major third, is this now in a range that most men could sing?
Everyone knows that Bruno Mars's songs are out of reach for the vast majority of male singers because of how high his voice is. However, if you pitch his songs down a major third (4 half-steps, 1/3 of an octave), would they then be in a range that an average man could pull off?
For example: https://vocaroo.com/12jLXuwOSrBw
Highest part of the song begins around 2:35

Maybe you could explain what your actual goal is. As it is, this question doesn't make a lot of sense because there isn't really an "average man" when it comes to singing.

@ToddWilcox how isn't there an average man vis-a-vis vocal range? There's an average male height, average male lifespan, etc... My goal is to see if Bruno Mars songs, 4 semitones down, are achievable for the average man without falsetto. I can pull off Bruno Mars songs 4 semitones down, and I wonder if this is normal for adult men.

Check out the tenor range for vox. I doubt if all B.M's songs will bring them into that range when dropped by M3.

If there really is an average male vocal range, then a simple web search should be able to find it and answer your question for you right there. In any case, if you can tell us more about why you’re looking for this dubious yes/no answer, we can probably help you with your actual question.

Is the singer a high tenor, low tenor, baritone, or bass? All have different ranges. Further, it depends on the lowest note in the song. Just because the highest note is accessible by lowering the key, that could move the lowest note out of range.

Maybe the point is more that "average male vocal range" is irrelevant here. You seem to be concerned about whether your own range is "normal," and for some reason using Bruno Mars songs as a proxy to discuss that. But even that concern is meaningless; you have the range you have and can perhaps develop and expand it. It's yours, and "normal" doesn't really have meaning or relevance to this discussion, unless you have reason to be worried that something is w

Bruno Mars is a tenor. Not a particularly high one. Look up vocal ranges of different voice types and see how shifting the range affects that. Major third would turn the range from Tenor to baritone. There are more baritone voices than tenor voices, but then for a tenor the low notes might be too low, for a bass the high notes would still be quite high.

My downvote is for every clause in the premise being meaninglessly vague. What is a vocal range? How you define it or measure it influences your conclusions dramatically. What counts as "pulling off" a song? Same issue. Who is the "average male singer"? That's kinda like asking how fast the average amateur runner runs 100m - you can't answer without defining exactly who counts as an average runner.

@user45266 I mean, if the average man, who wasn't a trained singer or anything, tried to sing along to this pitched-down song on the radio, would they be able to pull it off, or would they crack and flip into falsetto?

I made an arrangement of Mars' "When I Was Your Man" that an amateur men's choir sang, mostly in unison, with a bit of 2-part harmony. I took it down from C to E♭ (9 semitones). I expect the same would work for this piece (from D to F, maybe G).

I already pitched it down 4 semitones. The original key was F#/Gb

Why did you pitch "When I Was Your Man" down so much? The highest note in it is C5. Is Eb4 really a limit for most men?

It's not merely a matter of what notes one can physically hit; yes, most men can go rather higher, using falsetto, etc.. But rather, one must be able to (1) sing with a connected, musical line, and (2) be able to stay in that range without getting tired. Publishers of hymnals for congregational singing usually stick to the range A3-D5 (women) / A2-D4 (men); see https://www.renewingworshipnc.org/song-keys-for-maximum-participation/
